# How to perform leave one subject out cross-validation for a two-level imbalanced data

Tags: cross-validation

How can I perform leave-one-subject-out (LOSO) cross-validation for a two-level imbalanced data. Specifically, I have a binary class problem, whereby the imbalance between two classes lies in: (1) the number of participants (e.g. 100 patients and 50 controls), and, (2) number of recordings (e.g. some participants contribute 1 recording in total, while other contribute about 30), I am referring this as a two-level imbalanced data. For 10-fold CV, the recordings need to be balanced, which is relatively straightforward. For LOSO, the number of participants and recordings in both classes need to be balanced, which is now tricky. Should I over-sample both the number of participants and recordings? Is there any way I could assign class-weights while training the classifier? Thanks.